# How to suppress warning about unreadable disks?

Tags: macos, dual-boot, raid

I have a dual boot machine, High Sierra and Windows 10.  I have 4 disks in a software RAID created in Windows.  Every time I boot macOS, it warns me that these disks are unreadable and must be initialized.  How can I prevent this warning?  I don't think fstab can do it, because these are not recognizable partitions.